# Redirect to another endpoint after calling a function

Tags: go, gorilla

I have a subrouter with prefix `/api/a` and I want to redirect, all requests to endopoint with prefix `api/b/{aid}`, to `api/a` after calling a function (which sets context.) How to achieve this?

When there is a call to `/api/a/<whatever>`, I take aid from cookies and add to request context but there are other endpoints where cookies doesn't contain `aid` parameter so I take it as a route param. What I want is any call to `/api/b/{aid}/<whatever>` is redirected to `/api/a/<whatever>` after I set `aid` in its request context (from route param).

1. I absolutely don't want to use client side redirects, he doesn't need to know.
2. Also I know that I can pass directly to any function with http.Handler signature. Its exactly what I want to avoid.
3. There are a fixed set of endpoints in which cookie won't be set (and thats intended, so I don't want to set one) and this set would always be prefixed by say `/api/b/{aid}`.

Since there are 150+ endpoints and handlers already configured to the subrouter prefixed `/api/a` (lets call it A). There is another subrouter B with prefix `/api/b/{aid}`. I want to redirect all calls to subrouter B to subrouter A after calling a function. It won't be logical to copy the entire list of handlers for separate subrouter if I want the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set a value in the request context, then redirect to some other URL and expect to get that value. You have to pass that value as part of the redirect using a query param, or a cookie, etc. Or you can do this without a redirect, and call the handler for the redirected URL directly.

If you want to do this with a cookie, you can get the `aid` in a handler, set a cookie containing `aid` using `http.SetCookie`, and redirect using `http.Redirect`. The other handler should receive the cookie.

If you want to do this using a query param, you can write the redirect URL with the added query parameter, redirect using `http.Redirect`, and parse it in the other handler.

If you want to do this without a redirect, you can get `aid` in one handler, put it into the request context, and call the other handler directly:

```
request.WithContext(context.WithValue(request.Context(),key,aid))
otherHandler(writer,request)
```

You can automate forwarding to the other caller using `Router.Match` with a single handler:

- Register a handler for pathprefix `/api/b/{aid}/`
- Handler parses `aid`
- Handler rewrites a url `/api/a/<remaining path>`, sets `request.URL` to it, and  uses `router.Match` to find the corresponding path under `/api/a` subtree
- Handler calls the handler for `/api/a/<remaining path>`

Comment: edited the answer with a suggestion on how to do it with a single handler

Comment: Rewriting the URL doesn't tale it to new subrouter it remains there only.

Comment: You rewrite the URL to call router.Match